# Powershell: response times between Windows Servers

Tags: windows, powershell, server

This may be just a case of my google-fu not working properly, but I'm trying to get exact response times between a set of Windows Servers. I can use the following type in Powershell:

```
Test-Connection -ComputerName google.com -count 1
```

However this only gives you response times in milliseconds:

```
Source        Destination     IPV4Address      IPV6Address                              Bytes    Time(ms) 
------        -----------     -----------      -----------                              -----    -------- 
ComputerName  google.com      172.217.26.14                                             32       26
```

The applications we're using requires very quick response times (below 1ms) so it would be great if I as a simple layman could measure it in microseconds. I tried something like the following:

```
$startTime = Get-Date
$testConnection = Test-Connection -ComputerName google.com -count 1
$stopTime = Get-Date
$responseTime = $stopTime - $startTime
```

But this goes from 20-30 ms to 120 ms, presumably since my machine has to read dates and calculate differences which does take a few milliseconds.

I'm assuming that some form of application (maybe WireShark?) could measure in microseconds but I was not able to find this. I know that for example Active Directory login timestamps log even down to nanoseconds so it *ought* to be doable within the Powershell scripting framework.

Comment: As you noted, you're almost undoubtedly measuring the wrong thing, as you're measuring the length of time the cmdlet executed plus various overheads.  You can get a little closer to the metal by retrieving the ping status time from the returned value, but that's still measuring results of a protocol that likely has no relevance to your implementation in terms of data transferred and other considerations.  Wireshark captures and analysis of your protocol in action will be a more realistic measure.

Comment: Ah, yes, I was simply trying to see if the difference in using the Test-Connection output (which is in ms) as well as doing that but also using a timestamp before and after was of a huge difference. If it was only a few microseconds then meh, but it turns out it's larger than expected :) I haven't gone in-depth with WireShark yet, but would you happen to know if the timestamps used in it can measure in microseconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working solution that I've found to this is to use the -Format parameter of Get-Date with the following:

```
Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss:fffffff"
```

This gives you the time down to each individual tick, or 10 millionth of a second. For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 0):

You can get the *response time* like this :

```
Test-Connection www.google.com -Count 4 | Measure-Object -Property ResponseTime -Average
```

and you can use the **TimeSpan** Class to deal with different timespans

```
[timespan]::fromseconds((Test-Connection www.google.com -Count 4 | Measure-Object -Property ResponseTime -Average).average)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, this does help but I can't see this going lower than milliseconds. I'm looking for a way to get the number in microseconds. I'm beginning to think that it's because the Test-Connection commandlet can only measure in milliseconds... Any other ideas?

Comment: @MagneTism: I do not think Dot net have any thing to convert that to nanosecs. I will update if there is a way. Accepting the answer would be much appreciable

Comment: There are 10,000 Ticks to a millisecond, but I don't think this measurement (effectively ping) is likely to be equivalent to whatever he's doing since the protocol choice will have a dramatic effect on that timescale. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I dont think there is a better way to capture the response time. So highlight if any. And ticks won't be considered in order to convert into Nanosecs or further.

Comment: we have these below seconds, we can manually put the calculations for the nanosecs: 

Decisecond · Centisecond · Millisecond · Microsecond · Nanosecond · Picosecond · Femtosecond · Attosecond..
So, a nanosecond  is one-millionth of a millisecond

Comment: The issue is not to get the ping results or to output it, the Test-Connection commandlet does that perfectly. And, it gives me the time in milliseconds with $testConnection.ResponseTime so using [timespan] is not _really_ necessary. I'm beginning to think that a 3rd party application is necessary but I haven't been able to find one that measures connectivity in microseconds.